# Error while doing Data-Driven Testing in JMeter using data in Excel

Tags: excel, apache, jmeter, apache-poi

I am attempting to read xmls stored in one column of an Excel spreadsheet and fire them to a server using HTTP Sampler and then store the response xml in the same Excel.
This is the structure of my test plan in JMeter:
[image]

However I have encountered and error.
I am not able to pinpoint the exact place where the error is taking place but I have obtained the error message from the Results Tree are as follows:

for the JSR223 Sampler

> Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline
>   evaluation of: `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
>   import org.apache.poi.xssf.us . . . '' : Typed variable declaration :
>   Attempt to resolve method: parseInt() on undefined variable or class
>   name: INTEGER : at Line: 6 : in file: inline evaluation of:`import
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; import
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.us . . . '' : INTEGER .parseInt ( vars .get (
>   "counter" ) )   in inline evaluation of: ``import
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; import
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.us . . . '' at line number 6

The error in the HTTP Request Sampler's Response Data tab reads as:

```
Exception occured: Parsing xml error, xml string is:${RQI}
```

BeanShell Assertion error is :

> Assertion error: true Assertion failure: false Assertion failure
>   message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh
>   method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``import
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; import
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.us . . . '' Encountered ":" at line 6, column 65.

This is the code that I had used in the JSSR223 Sampler in the While Controller:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import java.io.*;

int i = INTEGER.parseInt(vars.get("counter"));
XSSFRow row = vars.getObject("book").getSheetAt(0).getRow(i);

vars.putObject("row", row);
for (int j = 1; j <= vars.getObject("book").getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); j++) {
    if (row.getCell(j) == null) {
        row.createCell(j).setCellValue("");
    }
}

String payload = row.getCell(1).toString();
 vars.put("RQI",payload);
//String password = row.getCell(2).toString();
// vars.put("password",password);
//String expectedResult = row.getCell(5).toString();
// vars.put("expectedResult",expectedResult);
```

Please assist. Also, feel free to ask for more information as I have left out the code for the other JSR223 Samplers in this post for brevity. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `INTEGER`? Do you mean [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)? Java class names are case sensitive.

Comment: I have corrected that. Thanks for pointing that out. But I still have errors and it seems like the loop keeps looping without and end. Below is the code for BeanShell 

String requestToApi = SampleResult.getSamplerData();

String responseFromApi = SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString(); 

vars.getObject("row").createCell(1).setCellValue(responseFromApi);

String stopWhile = null;

int i = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter"));
if (i >= vars.getObject("book").getSheetAt(0).getLastRowNum()){
 
 stopWhile = "OK";
 vars.put("stopWhile",stopWhile);
 
}

Comment: Please do not providing such infornations in comments. Instead edit your question. In your question the error clearly states `Attempt to resolve method: parseInt() on undefined variable or class name: INTEGER`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must change this line:

   ```
   INTEGER.parseInt(vars.get("counter"));
   ```

   to this one

   ```
   Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter"));
   ```

   check out Integer class JavaDoc - [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)
2. [You should be using JSR223 Test Elements instead of Beanshell test elements and you should be using `Groovy` language in the JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
3. You might find [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test) reference useful.